# How to filter instant vector by value then take range in promQL?

Tags: prometheus, metrics

Lets say I have some metric `metric` and I perform a selection over a dimension by doing `metric{ dim = "some value" }`. The result of this is an instant vector which I now want to filter by using a simple `> 0`. I expect the result of `metric{ dim = "some value" } > 0` to be another instant vector and this is what I gather from the documentation. I would now like to take a range of the resulting instant vector so I would expect

```
(metric{ dim = "some value" } > 0)[1m]
```

to be a perfectly legitimate query but I get complaints, if I write

```
(metric{ dim = "some value" } > 0)[1m:]
```

I perform a subquery but I don't think this is what I want because with a scrape interval of 10s I only get 2 values in my range instead of 6. How can I filter then range to get a range vector which I can pass into a function like `rate` or `delta`?

Comment: It'd help if you'd explain what you expect to do with the output of this.

Comment: @brian-brazil I updated it, I'd like to just pass into a function like ```delta```

Comment: `delta` is extremely rarely a function that you want, so I'm guessing it's more `deriv` you're looking for - so using `deriv` directly is what you want here without any filtering.

Answer (score 0):

With the new [subquery syntax](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) (introduced in [Prometheus version 2.7](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/4831)) you can do this with the below code.

Warning: These subqueries are expensive, i.e. create very high load on Prometheus. Use recording-rules when you use these queries regularly (in alerts, etc.).

```
(metric{ dim = "some value" } > 0 ) [2m:5s]
```

## Subquery syntax

`<instant_query>[<range>:<resolution>]`

- instant_query: a PromQL-function which returns an instant-vector)
- range: offset (back in time) to start the first subquery
- resolution: the size of each of the subqueries.